# Is there a way to create a playlist in YouTube that play a section of a video?

Tags: video, youtube

I would like to create a playlist of music to listen. It seems that the default YouTube playlist function only allow you add a whole video to a playlist, but I would like to add only a section of a video.

For example, [in this Karaoke stream of a Vtuber](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TkfUAFuLiJ4&t=0s), is there a way I can create a play list that play 8:04-9:32 and 11:18-14:06 of the video?

Currently the common solution would be to download the video, cut out the sections you need, upload those sections as full video to YouTube and create a playlist based on that. Not only it is really time-consuming to do so (the time for downloading the whole video and time for video editing), watching the video in the original channel is a support to the creator. I don't mind using plugin. I am even considering writing one if there is really no solution out there, but I would like to reconfirm I am not reinventing the wheels.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly it seems that there are no solution out there. YouTube originally have the function in their playlist but [have removed that more than 5 years ago](https://support.google.com/youtube/forum/AAAAiuErobUGipu_cCDScI/?hl=en&gpf=%23!topic%2Fyoutube%2FGipu_cCDScI).

I have written a minimalist solution for this and hope YouTube will add back this function some day.
https://cytsunny.github.io/youtube-playlist/

[Source Code](https://github.com/cytsunny/youtube-playlist)